# Search all occurences of a instance ids in the variable

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a bash variable which has the following content:

```
SSH exit status 255 for i-12hfhf578568tn
i-12hdfghf578568tn is able to connect
i-13456tg is not able to connect
SSH exit status 255 for 1.2.3.4
```

I want to search the string starting with `i-` and then extract only that instance id. So, for the above input, I want to have output like below:

```
i-12hfhf578568tn
i-12hdfghf578568tn
i-13456tg
```

I am open to use `grep`, `awk`, `sed`.
I am trying to achieve my task by using following command but it gives me whole line:
`grep -oE 'i-.*'<<<$variable`
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change your grep command to:

```
grep -oP 'i-[^\s]*' <<<$variable
```

**Tested on your input:**

```
$ cat test 
SSH exit status 255 for i-12hfhf578568tn
i-12hdfghf578568tn is able to connect
i-13456tg is not able to connect
SSH exit status 255 for 1.2.3.4

$ var=`cat test`

$ grep -oP 'i-[^\s]*' <<<$var                                                                                                                  
i-12hfhf578568tn
i-12hdfghf578568tn
i-13456tg
```

`grep` is exactly what you need for this task, `sed` would be more suitable if you had to reformat the input and `awk` would be nice if you had either to reformat a string or make some computation of some fields in the rows, columns

**Explanation:**

- `-P` is to use perl regex
- `i-[^\s]*` is a regex that will match literally `i-` followed by 0 to N non space character, you could change the `*` by a `+` if you want to impose that there is at least 1 char after the `-` or you could use `{min,max}` syntax to impose a range.

Let me know if there is something unclear.

Bonus:

Following the comment of Sundeep, you can use one of the improved versions of the regex I have proposed (the first one does use PCRE and the second one posix regex):

```
grep -oP 'i-\S*' <<<$var
```

or

```
grep -o 'i-[^[:blank:]]*' <<<$var
```

Comment: typo in first code: `i-[^\s*]` should be `i-[^\s]*`... and suggestions: 1) `[^\s]` is same as `\S` 2) PCRE not required here, can also use `grep -o 'i-[^[:blank:]]*'`

Comment: @Sundeep: Thanks a lot Sundeep! I really appreciate your feedbacks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use following too(I tested it with GNU `awk`):

```
echo "$var" | awk -v RS='[ |\n]' '/^i-/'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this code (Tested in unix)

```
echo $test | grep -o "i-[0-z]*"
```

Here,
-o # Prints only the matching part of the lines
i-[0-z]* # This regular expression, matches all the alphabetical and numerical characters following 'i-'.